# Pandera slow synthetic Dataframe generation if not eq schema

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-hypothesis, pandera

I am trying to learn the Pandera Library. When i try to automatically generate test Data from a DataFrameModel, it suddenly takes very long or crashes if i deviate from the minimal example in terms of limit checks.

Consider the Base example from the Pandera documentation: https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data_synthesis_strategies.html#strategies-and-examples-from-dataframe-models

I can expand it with lots of additional columns. Consider the Code:

```py
from pandera.typing import Series, DataFrame
import pandera as pa
import hypothesis


class InSchema(pa.DataFrameModel):
    column1: Series[int] = pa.Field(eq=10)
    column2: Series[float] = pa.Field(eq=0.25)
    column3: Series[str] = pa.Field(eq="foo")
    column4: Series[int] = pa.Field()
    column5: Series[int] = pa.Field(eq=123)
    column6: Series[int] = pa.Field(eq=123)
    column7: Series[int] = pa.Field(eq=123)


class OutSchema(InSchema):
    column4: Series[float]


@pa.check_types
def processing_fn(df: DataFrame[InSchema]) -> DataFrame[OutSchema]:
    return df.assign(column4=df.column1 * df.column2)



def test_processing_fn():
    dataframe = InSchema.example(size=5)
    processing_fn(dataframe)
    print(dataframe)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    gg= InSchema.strategy(size=5)
    test_processing_fn()
    print("Done!")
```

Alright. Now Observe the if i Change one columns limits to `unique=True`:

```py
from pandera.typing import Series, DataFrame
import pandera as pa
import hypothesis


class InSchema(pa.DataFrameModel):
# NOW UNIQUE
    column1: Series[int] = pa.Field(unique=True)
    column2: Series[float] = pa.Field(eq=0.25)
    column3: Series[str] = pa.Field(eq="foo")
    column4: Series[int] = pa.Field()
    column5: Series[int] = pa.Field(eq=123)
    column6: Series[int] = pa.Field(eq=123)
    column7: Series[int] = pa.Field(eq=123)


class OutSchema(InSchema):
    column4: Series[float]


@pa.check_types
def processing_fn(df: DataFrame[InSchema]) -> DataFrame[OutSchema]:
    return df.assign(column4=df.column1 * df.column2)



def test_processing_fn():
    dataframe = InSchema.example(size=5)
    processing_fn(dataframe)
    print(dataframe)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    gg= InSchema.strategy(size=5)
    test_processing_fn()
    print("Done!")
```

The Software is able to infer a dataframe.
But if I now change one check to an equivalent check (eq=123 <=> le=123 && ge= 123), it fails:

```py
from pandera.typing import Series, DataFrame
import pandera as pa
import hypothesis


class InSchema(pa.DataFrameModel):
    column1: Series[int] = pa.Field(unique=True)
    column2: Series[float] = pa.Field(eq=0.25)
    column3: Series[str] = pa.Field(eq="foo")
    column4: Series[int] = pa.Field()
    # EQUIVALENT CHECKS
    column5: Series[int] = pa.Field(le=123, ge=123)
    column6: Series[int] = pa.Field(eq=123)
    column7: Series[int] = pa.Field(eq=123)


class OutSchema(InSchema):
    column4: Series[float]


@pa.check_types
def processing_fn(df: DataFrame[InSchema]) -> DataFrame[OutSchema]:
    return df.assign(column4=df.column1 * df.column2)



def test_processing_fn():
    dataframe = InSchema.example(size=5)
    processing_fn(dataframe)
    print(dataframe)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    gg= InSchema.strategy(size=5)
    test_processing_fn()
    print("Done!")
```

Now i get an error:

> hypothesis.errors.Unsatisfiable: Unable to satisfy assumptions of example_generating_inner_function

My question is, why? If i use both restrictions (unique and ge/le) separated, it works but both cannot be satisfiable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Pandera has a fairly inefficient approach: they generate a custom strategy for the first part of the schema, and then use rejection sampling to filter out values which fail any subsequent filter.  That's why [their docs](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data_synthesis_strategies.html#check-strategy-chaining) recommend specifying the most-restrictive constraint as the base strategy.

As a Hypothesis maintainer I've been sad about this for several years, [opened this issue](https://github.com/unionai-oss/pandera/issues/404) three years ago, built some runtime optimizations in Hypothesis, and after reading this have [opened a PR](https://github.com/unionai-oss/pandera/pull/1503) so that hopefully Pandera users will actually get the performance features I made for them.

---

update: [the optimizations have been released in Pandera 0.18.1](https://github.com/unionai-oss/pandera/discussions/1522), on 2024-03-10.  On older versions, or if you still have performance issues, you might want to [use our pandas strategies directly](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/numpy.html#pandas) :-)